# 16.10 not seeing wifi devices or android hotspot

Tags: networking

Ive been using Ubuntu 16.10 for the last three months or so. I have been using a hotspot on my android phone to get on the internet.  Now the wifi option isnt showing up in the networking menu, no wifi devices are detected and I cant hotspot to my android phone.  What can be done.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
I ran this command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

and got

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

I ran this in mint 18 which Im using to ask this question.  Perhaps I should boot into Ub 16.10 and compare the output.  Thanks for the help so far.

EDIT 2/////////////
After running the same command in the actual system UB 16.10,  I got this output

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
```

It does not mention the kernnel or driver used.

Comment: Have you checked the additional drivers section? Or Broadcom drivers?

Comment: There should be a wifi switch button on your keyboard, pressing it may solve the problem. Do you have a wifi LED or something on your computer?

Comment: @ Sumeet Deshmukh   No I havenet, how is it done.

Comment: @– Андрей Череваткин   My old HP had a hard switch on the keyboards, but Im pretty sure my new HP doesnt.

Comment: I think the same adapter is used for bluetooth and wifi

Comment: go to Software and updates> Additional Drivers, this might work, give it a shot

Comment: Thanks, I compared  the additional drivers tab of updates to my old laptop and they were the same (no proprietry drivers) and the old one still works ok.  but while talking about drivers ,  Ive re-edited my question with the output from ub 16.10 and the last two lines are missing,  something to do with kernnel and drivers.